# ¿Como referenciar un archivo de configuración en C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Necesito referenciar un archivo de configuración para pasárselo a una clase, estoy usando .NET 5 y el ejemplo que tenía lo referenciaba usando la clase ConfigurationManager.AppSettings, sin embargo esto no está soportado en .NET 5, no termino de encontrar ejemplo de como realizar esto... ¿Cómo puedo referenciar un archivo de configuración en .NET 5.0? Gracias!

Comment: Si por net 5.0 te refieres a net core, puede que [esto](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) sea lo que estas buscando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo pudieras hacer de la siguiente forma. Agrega (o instala si es necesario) las siguientes dependencias en tu Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
```

Después tendrás que configurar el nombre del archivo en ConfigureAppConfiguration y mediante Dependency Injection puedes crear una interfaz y clase que lea tu archivo de configuración para que lo puedas utilizar libremente

```
internal static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        // To customize application configuration such as set high DPI settings or default font,
        // see https://aka.ms/applicationconfiguration.
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        var host = CreateHostBuilder().Build();
        Application.Run(host.Services.GetRequiredService<Form>());
    }

    static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder() =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((context, builder) =>
        {
            // Add ini configuration files...
            builder.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);

        })
       .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
       {
           services.AddSingleton<IAppSettings, AppSettings>();
       }).UseConsoleLifetime();
}
```

En mi caso esta es la interfaz y clase que utilize para leer el archivo appsetting.json

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
public interface IAppSettings
        {
            string Server { get; }
            string ExePath { get; }
    
            string GetValue(string property);
        }
    public class AppSettings: IAppSettings
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration configuration;
        public AppSettings()
        {

        }
        public AppSettings(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.configuration = configuration;
        }
        public string GetValue(string property)
        {
            return this.configuration.GetValue<string>(property) ?? "";
        }

        public string Server => GetValue("Server");
        public string ExePath => Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "/";
    }
```

No olvides crear tu archivo appsettings.json en la raiz de tu proyecto.
Te dejo mi archivo appsettings.json por si lo necesitas

```
{
  "exclude": [
    "**/bin",
    "**/bower_components",
    "**/jspm_packages",
    "**/node_modules",
    "**/obj",
    "**/platforms"
  ],
    "Server": "https://localhost:11111/"
}
```

Por último y no menos importante no olvides especificar en tu .csproj que el archivo appsettings.json se copie al momento de compilar la solucion

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="appsettings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!